# Where can I rent a motorbike in the Philippines?

Tags: motorcycles

I am going to Cebu, and I'm going to stay for 2 month. I am looking to rent a motorbike, scooter there.

Is it possible to rent a motorbike for 2 months? Looking to rent on a cheap budget, about 8,000 PHP (160 USD) a month.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally recommend [motorbike cebu](http://motorbike-cebu.business.site/) otherwise there is a popular rental service in the Philippines called [book2wheel](http://www.book2wheel.com/) you can chat with them online at their website or using their facebook page.

Otherwise, you can also explore ride-sharing options. As far as I remember Uber was suspended in the Philippines (not sure if it's working now, someone may add more information in a comment) but Arcade City was fully functional.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Cebu. But in the Philippines I would get in a taxi. Or ride the jeeneys around. You will see some shops with third-hand bikes set out front. Walk in and ask. Many will rent them. Or go to a taxi stand with 6 or 7 taxis parked and ask them. You will soon have a driver there who will take you to his uncle's to rent one. Tip the driver for this.

Many of the normal rental places are starting to refuse to rent to tourists. As it's too hard to recover the bikes when they leave. Expect to pay cash. They need to know where you are staying. If American your driving license is good for 6 months in the Philippines.

Have you ever driven around in the Philippines or Asia before? It is NOT American driving.